# Opening Android app by way of link

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a link that can be sent via email which when opened my app on an android device. And if the app isn't on the device, it will go to the Google store and search for the app

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

Create a filter in your Manifest to handle certain URLS, for example:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="your-domain.com" android:path="/your-app"/>
</intent-filter>
```

So if user has your app installed and opens http://your-domain.com/your-app, your app will be opened and be able to handle it.

Then, make http://your-domain.com/your-app redirect to Google Play (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.your.app) if opened directly without your app.

Comment: This means that [http://your-domain.com/your-app](http://your-domain.com/your-app) links to the Market...

Comment: Yes. You should own domain your-domain.com and make http://your-domain.com/your-app redirect to the Market.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest different, more safe approach. Put your link in form

```
market://details?id=<PACKAGE>
```

if will always redirect user to Google Play but if app is already installed user will see "Open" there. If not, "Install" will be visible so user can proceed.

Comment: Not all email client can have a link without the use of http or https

Comment: That's correct, it will work on android device only, but I you can always add this line to your mail "If you do not have application installed, please visit <link to google play>".