# Installing an application through QR code in android

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, mobile, qr-code

My scenario is as follows:

1. Whenever some person scan a Qr code of a particular app using any third party application like a barcode scanner through an android device  :

   ```
     a. If the scanned Qr code is not installed in the device it gets ,it open the url where it can be downloaded and installed.
     b. Otherwise it opens the installed app in the device.
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you want a QR Code to open your app, and you can edit your app:**

I think best way would be to create a link which:

- Will open you app if it is installed. You should use some *intent-filters* on your app to do this.
- Will open browser to your website if your app is not installed. Then you can forward from your website to your app on Google Play.

Read my answer here for more details on this: [Opening Android app by way of link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181055/opening-android-app-by-way-of-link/12181137#12181137)

Once you've created this especial link, you can create a QR Code from it here: http://qrdroid.com/generate

**If you want a QR Code to open any app:**

Then there's no direct way to do so, unfortunately.

Your only option would be to encode a link to Google Play. It would always link there but, if that app is already installed, at least an 'Open' button would be shown.

Answer (score 0):

The QR scanner should return the package name for that app, with that call the below function, this code works for me

```
    public void startApplication(Context context, String packageName) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent appStartIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (appStartIntent != null)
    {
        context.startActivity(appStartIntent);
    }
    // if the intent is null which means you have not installed the app then open the google play 
    else {
        Intent searchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
        searchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(searchIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: But i cannot customize the Qr code app. I want that if the link is clicked the app gets open or installed.

Comment: you dont need to customize the scanner, but at least you should have your own app to achieve what you said,yes?